# Building Android Studio project with HoloEverywhere fails

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-holo-everywhere

Whenever I try to build my project that contains HoloEverywhere as a dependency, I come across this error:

> Gradle:  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':HoloEverywhere Library:processDebugManifest'.
>
>   > java.lang.AssertionError (no error message)
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

**Stack trace:**

```
C:\workspace>gradlew assemble --stacktrace
The TaskContainer.add() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be remove
d in Gradle 2.0. Please use the create() method instead.
:ABS v4.3.1:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:packageDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:prepareDebugDependencies
:ABS v4.3.1:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:compileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:packageDebugJar UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:packageReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:prepareReleaseDependencies
:ABS v4.3.1:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:compileRelease UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:ABS v4.3.1:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:packageDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:prepareDebugDependencies
:Crouton v1.8.1:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:compileDebug UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:packageDebugJar UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:packageDebugLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:packageDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:bundleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:packageReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:prepareReleaseDependencies
:Crouton v1.8.1:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:compileRelease UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:packageReleaseJar UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:packageReleaseLocalJar UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:assembleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:Crouton v1.8.1:assemble UP-TO-DATE
:HoloEverywhere Library:mergeDebugProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:HoloEverywhere Library:packageDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:HoloEverywhere Library:prepareWorkspaceABSV431UnspecifiedLibrary UP-TO-DATE
:HoloEverywhere Library:prepareDebugDependencies
:HoloEverywhere Library:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:HoloEverywhere Library:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:HoloEverywhere Library:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:HoloEverywhere Library:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:HoloEverywhere Library:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:HoloEverywhere Library:processDebugManifest
[AndroidManifest.xml:1] Could not find element /manifest/application.
[AndroidManifest.xml:1] Could not find element /manifest/application.
[AndroidManifest.xml:1] Could not find element /manifest/application.
[AndroidManifest.xml:1] Could not find element /manifest/application.
[AndroidManifest.xml:1] Could not find element /manifest/application.
[AndroidManifest.xml:1] Could not find element /manifest/application.
[AndroidManifest.xml:1] Could not find element /manifest/application.
:HoloEverywhere Library:processDebugManifest FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':HoloEverywhere Library:processDebugManifest'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':HoloEverywhere Library:processDebugManifest'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:179)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:232)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:142)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:83)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockReleasingTaskExecuter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ContextualisingTaskExecuter.execute(ContextualisingTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter$1.run(CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.java:39)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:112)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.execute(CacheLockAcquiringTaskExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:57)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:282)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.executeTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:48)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:27)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:89)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter$1.run(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:31)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:124)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:112)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:134)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:79)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.execute(TaskCacheLockHandlingBuildExecuter.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:50)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:201)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:174)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:139)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:39)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:50)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:32)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:26)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:33)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:130)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:48)Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException
        at com.android.builder.AndroidBuilder.doMerge(AndroidBuilder.java:475)
        at com.android.builder.AndroidBuilder.mergeLibraryManifests(AndroidBuilder.java:461)
        at com.android.builder.AndroidBuilder.processManifest(AndroidBuilder.java:301)
        at com.android.builder.AndroidBuilder$processManifest.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAppManifest.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAppManifest.groovy:65)
        at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.groovy:71)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject$MetaClassAdapter.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:216)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.BeanDynamicObject.invokeMethod(BeanDynamicObject.java:122)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:147)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAppManifest_Decorated.invokeMethod(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.util.ReflectionUtil.invoke(ReflectionUtil.groovy:23)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:217)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:199)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:526)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:509)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 70 more


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 52.879 secs
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

There is an issue in the manifest merger that requires the library to have an application node in its manifest. So just edit Holoeverywhere's manifest and add

```
<application />
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been banging my head for a while with this issue, and this totally nails it. Do you have any idea whether this is actually a bug or if it's intended?

Comment: Also, it seems you need to specify the `minSdkVersion`.

Comment: @goncalossilva, since he sad "There is an issue in the manifest merger [...]" I'm assuming it's not intended. Just pointing out.

Comment: This mostly fixes the error `Could not find element /manifest/application`