# Changing color of date picker dialog programmatically

Tags: java, android, datepicker

I'm using the DatePickerDialog in android and trying to change the colors of it when it pops up.  I can change the button text color but can't seem to find a way to change the other colors.  Here's a picture to illustrate:

[image]

Outlined in black are the areas that I would to change to blue.  Anything that is green I would like to change to blue.  Also here is the code I used to change button text color:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                        int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                        int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                        //System.out.println("the selected " + mDay);
                        DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                                new mDateSetListener(), mYear, mMonth, mDay);

                        dialog.show();

                        Button ok = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
                        ok.setTextColor(Color.rgb(64, 131, 207));

                        Button cancel = dialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
                        cancel.setTextColor(Color.rgb(64, 131, 207));
```

Is there a way to change these colors or a general color style that I can change?  Everything defaults to that darker green color.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: I have gone down this path before and I am just warning you the UI identifiers change with the Android OS so it will be hard to find a universal solution unless you create your own DatePickerDialog. I had an application that worked great in Lollipop and broke when I first ran it on Android M.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if the default color of `DatePickerDialog` can be changed but you can use the [holoeverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere)
 library which would not only make your `DatePickerDialog` look good but the entire app as a whole look good. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189052/add-holoeverywhere-to-project-in-android-studio)
you can find how to get the library in your android studio.