# Replacing old library with another

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

I'm new in android programming , I downloaded project that uses holoeverywhere library so I wont to know if I can replace it by another one (like ActionBarSherlock replaced by AppCompat ) ? the project uses those , how I deal with it?

```
import org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity;
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.LinearLayout;
import org.holoeverywhere.widget.datetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog;
```

I found this tutoria [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17189052/add-holoeverywhere-to-project-in-android-studio) but I its not working for me !
I can replace it with new library according to my code (my imports) ?
Please I need any solution !!

Comment: how old is that project?

Comment: I had hard time when replacing ActionBarSherlock with AppCompact, sorry but you have to manually change code.

Comment: Use `Find and Replace` function of `Android Studio` to replace different parts in the package name of 2 libs. That will automate a bit but still manual